# Eclipse CDT Custom Compiler Error Parsing Plugin

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm using an uncommon C compiler with Eclipse CDT.  I have a make file setup which is nice, but I'd like IDE integration with the error / warning output of my compiler.

Does anybody know what steps I can take to write a plugin for parsing / supporting my compilers output?  I think it should be easy but there is a barrier of entry of figuring out where to start.  Would be nice if Eclipse would let me do New -> Compiler Error Parser Plugin, or something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite that simple...

First of all make sure you have the Eclipse PDE (Plug-in Development Environment) and CDT SDK installed. If not then you'll need to tell Eclipse to download them (Help -> Install New Software).

Then, create a new Plug-In project. In its Extensions tab, add a new extension against point org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser. You will then have to write some java code to actually implement it. Fortunately the PDE makes the meta-work relatively straightforward; you put the name of your class in the appropriate box and click on the "class*" hyperlink and it will offer to create a skeleton class for you.

I suggest you grab the source code to the CDT and have a look at GCCErrorParser.java as an illustration of the sorts of things yours will have to do.

Finally, when you're ready to test it, set up a debug configuration of type Eclipse Application. (This will spawn a second instance of Eclipse; it has to use a different workbench.) Go into the properties of your C project, Settings panel, Error Parsers tab and switch on your shiny new error parser.

Comment: The answer is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse CDT 7.0.1 it's pretty simple. Just add a new error parser 
under **Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ Build -> Settings**
and add regular expression with 3 groups: filename, linenumber and error description.

For example, for Visual Studio compiler regexp will be:

```
(.*?)\((\d*)\)\s:\s(.*error.*)

$1 - filename
$2 - line number
$3 - error description
```

Comment: It's a pity it's not available for the External build tool.

Answer (score 2):

IBM has published a step-by-step guide to how you can write your own CDT parser, its available [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPSQF_9.1.1/com.ibm.etools.aix.cpp.doc.user/html/error_parser_help/html/error_parser.html)

Relevant google search for future proofing should be:
https://www.google.com/search?q=ibm+eclipse+write+cdt+parser&oq=ibm+eclipse+write+cdt+error+parser

Comment: The link is not working. If you had provided a title, I could google it myself.

Comment: @sadik Google "ibm eclipse write cdt error parser", first hit. Updated answer with working link.

Answer (score 1):

In CDT 7 there is going to be a regular expression error parser included which should make this sort of thing much simpler. There are some details on the [faq](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_Error_Parser_.28or_The_project_seems_to_build_file.2C_but_doesn.27t_parse_my_error_output_what_can_I_do.3F.29).

CDT 7.0 won't be released until the end of June, but you could try milestone builds to see if it does what you want. These can be downloaded [here](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/). You'll need to have a matching milestone version of the eclipse platform too.

Comment: The answer is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this plugin:

http://www.isystem.com/downloads/downloads/204-Eclipse-Downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

is this working ?

```
(.*)\((\d+)\)\s:\sError(.*)
```

file: $1
line: $2
desc: $3

.
srkos

Answer (score 0):

In CDT 8 this functionality does not require a plugin. I have support for several compilers and build systems using simple regular expressions. See screenshot [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn80#Error_Parsers). You can test the regexes directly in the console output before copying them to this dialog. If you need to move them between machines, the resulting parsers are stored in your workspace under .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core