# How do I write a multiline build error parser for Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, ocaml, eclipse-cdt

I want to use the Makefile-based builder of Eclipse's CDT (8.1.2) to build an OCaml project.

However, the OCaml compiler outputs multiline error messages with line number and error reason on different lines (Example below).

Can I create a build error parser that covers multiple lines of build output, and if yes, how?

Example error message that I'd like to parse:

```
File "src/filename.ml", line 91, characters 35-54:
Error: Unbound value foo
```

Desired output:

Description: Unbound value foo
File: src/filename.ml
Line: 91

(File and Line are trivial, but the Description is the problem.)

#### Update:

I now have a build error parser for OCaml - from the OcaIDE project.

I use the CDT Make builder for driving the build and OCaIDE's error parser for error parsing. OCAide's error parser also has the advantage that it can point to a specific span in a line that is reported to cause the error, something CDT's regex parser can't do.

So my OCaml-related problem is solved. However, the general problem of multi-line error parsing remains.

Comment: do you already have a basic working builder (ie. which works in eclipse when there's no compilation error)?

Comment: Some of those messages can be HUGE --for example, a module parametrized by a mismatched module type.

Comment: @didierc Yes I have a working builder. I use the builder from CDT that just works with Makefiles.

Comment: ah right, there's indeed OcaIDE, good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT Custom Compiler Error Parsing Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298985/eclipse-cdt-custom-compiler-error-parsing-plugin)